# How to make row/column of non-fixed sized parent fill the whole space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to do it with Expanded but I am getting 'RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming width constraints are unbounded.' which is expected because the size of parent is not defined.

```
Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'something',
            style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline2,
          ),
          Expanded(
           child: Container(),
          ),
        ]
)
```

Comment: This is because, as the error says, the parent widget hasn't a size, so the Row will grow infinitely. Try to wrap the Row with a SizedBox and set a width.

Comment: Yeah, But I want to set its width to the maximum available space and the size of devices differ so I don't have the exact size. I'd have to use MediaQuery.Size() for the size but I am searching for something like Expanded() but with row/column size set to maximum free space.

Comment: You can use `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width`, that will get the width of the screen for every device.

Comment: And i believe that the Expanded must be wrapping the Row instead of the Row wrapping the Expanded.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Row` is wrapped within an `Column` widget it will take up all of the available space and give your `Row` the required Parent width. This will be rendered at the top of the `Column`.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/testScreen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Test'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'something',
                  style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline2,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you want the widget to take up entire height as well then wrap it again with an `Expanded`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/testScreen';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'something',
                  style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline2,
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Container(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

If you do not give the Row this fixed area it will expand indefinitely off the side of your screen

Non `Column` solution

```
 body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'something',
              style: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme.headline2,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: This column solution looks good but is there any other implementation where I don't have to use a column with just one widget.

Comment: Updated to show usage of a non `Column` solution. `SingleChildScrollView` also gives you the benefit of being able to build down without render issues.